# How to use different Service Connection for every stage in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

When using [multistage pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/whats-new-with-azure-pipelines/) from yaml in Azure Pipelines and every stage is deploying resources to a separate environment, I'd like to use a dedicated service connection for each stage. In my case every stage is making use of the same deployment jobs, i.e. yaml templates. So I'm using a lot of variables that have specific values dependent on the environment. This works fine, except for the service connection.

Ideally, the variable that contains the service connection name, is added to the stage level like this:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
    # (Several build-stage specific jobs here)

- stage: DeployToDEV
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  variables:
    AzureServiceConnection: 'AzureSubscription_DEV' # This seems like a logical solution
  jobs:
    # This job would ideally reside in a yaml template
    - job: DisplayDiagnostics
      pool:
        vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
      steps:
        - checkout: none
        - task: AzurePowerShell@4
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: $(AzureServiceConnection)
            scriptType: inlineScript
            inline: |
              Get-AzContext
            azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion

- stage: DeployToTST
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  variables:
    AzureServiceConnection: 'AzureSubscription_TST' # Same variable, different value
  jobs:
    # (Same contents as DeployToDEV stage)
```

When this code snippet is executed, it results in the error message:

> There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid.
>   Job DisplayDiagnostics: Step AzurePowerShell input
>   ConnectedServiceNameARM references service connection
>   $(AzureServiceConnection) which could not be found. The service
>   connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For
>   authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.

So, it probably can't [expand the variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#expansion-of-variables) `AzureServiceConnection` soon enough when the run is started. But if that's indeed the case, then what's the alternative solution to make use of separate service connections for every stage?

One option that works for sure is setting the service connection name directly to all tasks, but that would involve duplicating identical yaml tasks for every stage, which I obviously want to avoid.

Anyone has a clue on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is actually really annoying for me as I need to be able to specify them as we have Development and Production in different Azure Subscriptions and it's _really_ bad practice to hardcode the variables into the files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently you can not pass a variable as a serviceConnection. 
Apparently the service connection name is picked up on push/commit and whatever that is there will be picked up.

E.g. if you have a $(variable) it will pick $(variable) instead of the value.

Workaround I have used so far is to use a template for the steps at each stage and pass a different parameter with the serviceConnection.

Refer: https://github.com/venura9/azure-devops-yaml/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml for a sample implementation. you are more than welcome to pull request with updates.

```
- stage: DEV
  displayName: 'DEV(CD)'
  condition: and(succeeded('BLD'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'))
  dependsOn: 
   - BLD
  variables: 
    stage: 'dev'
  jobs:

  - job: Primary_AustraliaSouthEast
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImage)
    steps:
    - template: 'pipelines/infrastructure/deploy.yml'
      parameters: {type: 'primary', spn: 'SuperServicePrincipal', location: 'australiasoutheast'}
    - template: 'pipelines/application/deploy.yml'
      parameters: {type: 'primary', spn: 'SuperServicePrincipal'}
```

Comment: This worked well for me and allowed me to reduce duplication.  Too bad a simple variable is not an option in this case.

Comment: Agreed, two years later it's still in the workaround territory :(

Comment: I agree this is clumsy.  I think the reason for this lies in the authorization of the pipeline to use the Service Connection.  This authorization must be made before the pipeline can be run.   See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue in 2024.
Another workaround is to load all the variable groups in your initial yml and then for each stage to reload the variable group that will replace the value for the current stage. example:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
...
variables:
 - group: SetOfSubscriptionNames # That's how I use it and load the variables from a library set. Later I reload the same variable set from the stage.
 - name: AzureSubscription_DEV
   value: <AzureAppServiceConnectionNameHere>
 - name: AzureSubscription_TST
   value: <AzureAppServiceConnectionNameHere>
...
stages:
- stage: DeployToDEV
  ...
  variables:
    AzureServiceConnection: 'AzureSubscription_DEV' 
  ...
- stage: DeployToTST
  ...
  variables:
    AzureServiceConnection: 'AzureSubscription_TST' 
  ...
```