# Azure Pipeline how to read libraries variables within a template loop

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am trying to load the different variables groups in the template loop. I wish, in each iteration to read in a different eg. `group: xadodemo-dev` group(library), then in the next iteration different one to give me a different context/values per environment. I hoped to use a construct like `group: xadodemo-${{ environment }}` but it error out with:

"Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
Job dev: Step  input awsCredentials references service connection $(awsCredentials) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.
Job ppd: Step  input awsCredentials references service connection $(awsCredentials) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to [https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."](https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.%22)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyHCz.png)

I do not know why this line `environment: xadodemo-${{ environment }}` when parsed by ADO rendering engine is interpreted literally as `$(awsCredentials)` and not what is in the libs value for it as `111111111111-dev-aws`.

As work a around I was creating/coping values from libraries into the parameter object and hardcoding within the pipline but for some projects there is too many different values per environment.

Library name: xadodemo-dev

```
awsCredentials: 111111111111-dev-aws
awsRegion: eu-west-1
```

Library name: xadodemo-ppd

```
awsCredentials: 22222222222-ppd-aws
awsRegion: us-east-1
```

```
├── ci
│   ├── awscredentials-pipeline.yaml
│   └── awscredentials.template.yaml
```

awscredentials-pipeline.yaml

```
name: awscredentials-$(Rev:r)

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-20.04"

parameters:
- name       : environments
  displayName: Environments
  type       : object
  default    :
  - dev
  - ppd

stages:
- stage      : awscredentials
  displayName: awscredentials
  jobs       :
  - template  : awscredentials.template.yaml
    parameters:
       environments: ${{ parameters.environments }}
```

awscredentials.template.yaml

```
parameters:
- name       : environments
  displayName: 'List of environments (map)'
  type       : object

jobs:
- ${{ each environment in parameters.environments }}:
  - deployment : ${{ replace(environment,'-','_') }}
    displayName: ${{ environment }}
    environment: xadodemo-${{ environment }}

    variables:
    - group: xadodemo-${{ environment }}
    - name : ENVIRONMENT
      value: ${{ environment }}

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout   : self
          - download   : none
          - script: echo awsCredentials $(awsCredentials), awsRegion $(awsRegion)
            displayName: echo
          - task       : AWSShellScript@1
            displayName: awsCredentials
            env:
              ADO_DEMO_SECRET: $(ado_demo_secret)
            inputs:
              awsCredentials      : $(awsCredentials)
              regionName          : $(awsRegion)
              failOnStandardError : false
              args                : ""
              scriptType          : inline
              inlineScript        : |
                #!/bin/bash
                echo "environment     ${{ environment }}"
                echo "awsCredentials  $(awsCredentials)"
                echo "awsRegion       $(awsRegion)"
                echo "ADO_DEMO_SECRET $ADO_DEMO_SECRET"
                env | grep ado_demo
```

Comment: My issue seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57520028/how-to-use-different-service-connection-for-every-stage-in-azure-pipelines?rq=1 and the only Service Connection input for the task seems to render differently then others. So, I am happy to hardcode the service connection in parameters when calling the template. Then the template in each iteration it loads library vars as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with pio2pio, currently the feasible way is to hardcode the service connection in parameters when calling the template.

In addition, it is a known issue that **Service Connection cannot be specified by variable in stages** and it has already been reported here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/5964 and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/using-a-variable-for-the-service-connection-result/676259.

But according to the product group's feedback, this feature is already in backlog. Due to some other priority work they are not able to priorities this. You could follow and vote the thread: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/using-a-variable-for-the-service-connection-result/676259, or create a new suggestion ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to help track this ongoing feature.