# Azure DevOps Npm Authenticate Task Endpoint

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am currently trying to run the 'npmAuthenticate' task within my Azure DevOps pipeline but seem to be running into an issue when the 'customEndpoint' is a set varaible. It appears to work just fine if I pass the same Service Connection Name in as a parameter but not when setting as a variable else where in the pipeline.

Broken:

```
      jobs:
      - job: Create_Files
        displayName: Create Files
        steps:
        - task: Bash@3
          displayName: Setting npm endpoint
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=npm_endpoint]ExampleEndpointName"
        - task: Bash@3
          displayName: Debugging step to print variable
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              echo "Printing npm endpoint - $(npm_endpoint)"
        - task: npmAuthenticate@0
          inputs:
            workingFile: '${{ parameters.npmc_file }}'
            customEndpoint: '$(npm_endpoint)'
```

When I try to run this I get the following error within Azure DevOps:

**Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
Job Create_Files: Step  input customEndpoint references service connection $(npm_endpoint) which could not be found. The service connection does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.**

If I set the customEndpoint as a parameter being passed in with the exact same value it works fine.

```
jobs:
  - job: Create_Files
    displayName: Create Files
    steps:
    - task: npmAuthenticate@0
      inputs:
        workingFile: '${{ parameters.npmc_file }}'
        customEndpoint: '${{ parameters.npm_endpoint }}'
```

Is there something I might be doing wrong here or has anybody seen anything like this?

**EDIT** Put in Debug step to print variable. When run it shows the correct value.

Comment: How are you setting the variable? Can you include that?

Comment: @ddastrodd on the broken run? Its here - 
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=npm_endpoint]ExampleEndpointName"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**

Simply say, not support now.

You are using a runtime variable.

But run time variables **aren't supported** for **service connection** OR azure subscription. The variable will get initialized at the run time.

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10376#issuecomment-514477023

You can follow below method to use different service connection:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57520153/6261890

But still need point that, parameters are expanded just before the pipeline runs, hardcode the specific service connection is unavoidable, this is by design.

***Also clearly in this official document:***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-service-connection

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your variable like this  `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=npm_endpoint]ExampleEndpointName"` and it will "get processed during runtime".

But you are trying to use that variable like this `'$(npm_endpoint)'` which will "get processed during runtime before a task runs".

You are trying to use the variable before it is set.

See **Understand variable syntax** on this page for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch.

Comment: I have read this and still can't see what I'm doing wrong here. It says to do what I'm doing. To confirm, I created a task in between when the variable is set and when I try to use it and ran an 'echo $(npm_endpoint)' and it prints the correct value.

Comment: Can you include that in your code snippet? Maybe that will help us spot the issue.

Comment: Edited code snippet to show debug step where when run shows the variable value.